# Is it ok to use multiple $add within a ng-click in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-click

I have been able to get the behavior that I am looking for in this code but I just wanted to make sure I was heading down the right path. I have read alot about event listeners as well but wasn't able to figure out how to implement that so I was wondering if my code works just as good, better, or worse.

In my service:

```
.factory('Messages', function($firebaseArray, FBURL, $window) {
  var messagesRef = new $window.Firebase(FBURL + '/messages');
  return $firebaseArray(messagesRef);
})

.factory('Chatroom', function($firebaseArray, FBURL, $window) {
  var chatroomRef = new $window.Firebase(FBURL + '/chatroom');
  return $firebaseArray(chatroomRef);
})
```

Then in my controller:

```
  $scope.messages = Messages;
  $scope.chatroom = Chatroom;

  $scope.addMessage = function(message) {
    $scope.messages.$add({
      text: message.text,
      userName: message.userName
    });
      $scope.chatroom.$add({
        text: message.text,
        userName: message.userName,
    });
    message.text="";
   }
```

So right now I am adding the text and username to both child nodes on ng-click. If I wanted to add this to more child nodes like profile and whatever else it may be can I just keep putting in the $add that references the different node or is that bad practice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the same information to multiple locations in your Firebase Database is called fan-out and is a common practice. So while it depends on your exact needs, it is not by definition bad to duplicate the data. See this [blog post about denormalization on the Firebase site](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html).

You might want to consider using a single multi-location `update()` statement instead of two separate `$add()` calls. See for an example this question: [Firebase: How do I update multiple resources atomically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437695/firebase-how-do-i-update-multiple-resources-atomically) and [this blog post on the Firebase web site](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html).

Comment: Thank you again for the answer Frank! I will check out the resources that you listed and see if I can update my code. Thank you.

Comment: It took some trial and error but I was finally able to implement the multi-location update() and wow what a difference it makes. Thank you again for the resources as they have helped me solve a bunch of questions I had.

Comment: Hey Frank you seem to have all of the good answers for Firebase after looking through different firebase question on stack overflow. I have put up another question that I am stuck on right now so if you get a chance I would really appreciate your insight on this topic. Thanks again!