# Concat multiple database actions into one single transaction in Angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, rxjs5, angularfire2

I have a view that `subscribe` to a `FirebaseListObservable` and a form that does CRUD operations on a *range* of objects in that list.

It will iterate over the keys and update the database like so:

```
let list = this.angularFire.database.list('items/' + listkey);
keys.forEach((key) => list.update(key, item[key]));
```

The problem is that the subscription issue a new list for each update, whereas I only need the list when all the transactions are complete.

I have tried to manipulate the list before updating the database using the `FirebaseObjectObservable` on the `listkey` but it throws an error due to invalid characters in the metafields (like `$key` and `$exist`).

Right now I am using a `debounceTime` on the subscription but I am not sure if that is the proper implementation or not.

*Is there a way to concat the updates into a single transaction?*

Comment: There're `merge` and `concat` operators but from your description I don't really understand what is the problem and how is it implemented...

Comment: I could elaborate on the implementation some more, but I think it is pretty generic. I want to update parts of a `FirebaseListObservable` as a single transaction. Not sure how I would do that using `merge` or `concat` operators but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437695/firebase-how-do-i-update-multiple-resources-atomically

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. Thanks, will try and implement!

Comment: Yep, follow the [answer linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17438028/6680611) and call `list.$ref.ref.update` where `list` is the observable in your question. Note that for multi-location updates you don't call `list.update` (which is a wrapper around the SDK); you call it directly on the SDK ref.